# Two implementation of virtual batch norm lead to two differents results

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization, tensorflow-xla

## Introductory question:

should both example code lead to different behavior on training (any loss / any optimizer) ?

```
# first code
inputs1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[16,1,32,32], dtype=tf.float32)
inputs2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[16,1,32,32], dtype=tf.float32)
full_inputs = tf.concat([inputs1, inputs2], axis=0)
with tf.variable_scope('convnet'):
     outputs = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, kernel_size=[3,3], num_outputs=1, stride=[1,1], padding='VALID', data_format='NCHW')

# second code
inputs1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[16,1,32,32], dtype=tf.float32)
inputs2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[16,1,32,32], dtype=tf.float32)
full_inputs = tf.concat([inputs1, inputs2], axis=0)

with tf.variable_scope('convnet'):
    outputs1 = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs1, kernel_size=[3,3], num_outputs=1, stride=[1,1], padding='VALID', data_format='NCHW')

with tf.variable_scope('convnet', reuse=True):
    outputs2 = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs2, kernel_size=[3,3], num_outputs=1, stride=[1,1], padding='VALID', data_format='NCHW')

outputs = tf.concat([outputs1, outputs2], axis=0)
```

## My real case scenario:

I'm trying to implement virtual batch norm, I have two implementations which doesn't behave the same way widely inspired by the [improved gan repository](https://github.com/openai/improved-gan). Both implementation shown here are simplified to keep mostly what is different between them.

### First implementation:

```
@add_arg_scope
def vbn_single(x, epsilon=1e-5, scope=None):
    assert isinstance(epsilon, float)
    shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
    if shape[0] is None:
        half_size = x.shape[0] // 2
    else:
        half_size = shape[0] // 2
    needs_reshape = len(shape) != 4
    if needs_reshape:
        orig_shape = shape
        if len(shape) == 2:
            x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], shape[1], 0, 0])
        elif len(shape) == 1:
            x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], 1, 1, 1])
        else:
            assert False, shape
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
    batch_size = int(x.get_shape()[0])
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'VBN'):
        ref_half = tf.slice(x, [0,0,0,0], [half_size, shape[1], \
                            shape[2], shape[3]])
        gamma = tf.get_variable("gamma", [1,shape[1],1,1],
                    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.))
        beta = tf.get_variable("beta", [1,shape[1],1,1],
                    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))
        ref_mean, ref_var = tf.nn.moments(ref_half, [0,2,3], \
                                          keep_dims=True)
        inv_std = tf.rsqrt(ref_var + epsilon)
        coeff = inv_std * gamma
    return (x * coeff) + (beta - ref_mean * coeff)

inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[32, 1, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32)
reference_batch = tf.get_variable('reference_batch', initializer=reference_array)
full_inputs = tf.concat([reference_batch, inputs], axis=0)
L = []
with tf.variable_scope('convnet'):
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs, [...], \
                                      scope='Layer0'))
    L.append(vbn_single(L[-1], scope='Norm0'))
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ0')
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(L[-1], [...], \
                                      scope='Layer1'))
    L.append(vbn_single(L[-1], scope='Norm1'))
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activq')
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(L[-1], [...], \
                                      scope='Layer2'))
    L.append(vbn_single(L[-1], scope='Norm2'))
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ2')
shape = L[-1].get_shape().as_list()
half_size = shape[0] // 2
L.append(tf.slice(L[-1], [half_size,0,0,0], \
              [half_size, shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]]))
L.append(tf.reduce_mean(L[-1], axis=[2,3]))
L.append(tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(L[-1], num_outputs=2))
# loss accuracy and optimizer
```

Everything seems to work ok, validation and training accuracy converge up, and loss going down.

### Second implementation

```
class Vbn_double(object):
    def __init__(self, x, epsilon=1e-5, scope=None):
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
        needs_reshape = len(shape) != 4
        if needs_reshape:
            orig_shape = shape
            if len(shape) == 2:
                if data_format == 'NCHW':
                    x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], shape[1], 0, 0])
                else:
                    x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], 1, 1, shape[1]])
            elif len(shape) == 1:
                x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], 1, 1, 1])
            else:
                assert False, shape
            shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
        with tf.variable_scope(scope):
            self.epsilon = epsilon
            self.scope = scope
            self.mean, self.var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0,2,3], \
                                                keep_dims=True)
            self.inv_std = tf.rsqrt(self.var + epsilon)
            self.batch_size = int(x.get_shape()[0])
            out = self._normalize(x, self.mean, self.inv_std)
            if needs_reshape:
                out = tf.reshape(out, orig_shape)
            self.reference_output = out

    def __call__(self, x):
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
        needs_reshape = len(shape) != 4
        if needs_reshape:
            orig_shape = shape
            if len(shape) == 2:
                if self.data_format == 'NCHW':
                    x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], shape[1], 0, 0])
                else:
                    x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], 1, 1, shape[1]])
            elif len(shape) == 1:
                x = tf.reshape(x, [shape[0], 1, 1, 1])
            else:
                assert False, shape
        with tf.variable_scope(self.scope, reuse=True):
            out = self._normalize(x, self.mean, self.inv_std)
            if needs_reshape:
                out = tf.reshape(out, orig_shape)
        return out

    def _normalize(self, x, mean, inv_std):
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
        assert len(shape) == 4
        gamma = tf.get_variable("gamma", [1,shape[1],1,1],
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.))
        beta = tf.get_variable("beta", [1,shape[1],1,1],
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))
        coeff = gamma * inv_std
        return (x * coeff) + (beta - mean * coeff)

inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[32, 1, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32)
reference_batch = tf.get_variable('reference_batch', initializer=reference_array)
L = []
vbn = {}
with tf.variable_scope('convnet'):
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(reference_batch, [...], \
                                      scope='Layer0'))
    vbn['Norm0'] = Vbn_double(L[-1], scope='Norm0')
    L.append(vbn['Norm0'].reference_output)
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ0')
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(L[-1], [...], \
                                      scope='Layer1'))
    vbn['Norm1'] = Vbn_double(L[-1], scope='Norm1')
    L.append(vbn['Norm1'].reference_output)
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ1')
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(L[-1], [...], \
                                      scope='Layer2'))
    vbn['Norm2'] = Vbn_double(L[-1], scope='Norm2')
    L.append(vbn['Norm2'].reference_output)
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ2')

with tf.variable_scope('convnet', reuse=True):
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs, [...], \
                                      scope='Layer0'))
    L.append(vbn['Norm0'](L[-1]))
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ0')
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(L[-1], [...], \
                                      scope='Layer1'))
    L.append(vbn['Norm1'](L[-1]))
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ1')
    L.append(tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(L[-1], [...], \
                                      scope='Layer2'))
    L.append(vbn['Norm2'](L[-1]))
    L.append(tf.nn.relu(L[-1], name='Activ2')
L.append(tf.reduce_mean(L[-1], axis=[2,3]))
L.append(tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(L[-1], num_outputs=2))
# loss accuracy and optimizer
```

Here only training converge (but with slightly different curve than first implementation), while validation loss increase and accuracy stay at random guess.

As a matter of details, I'm using GPU, tensorflow 1.2.1 with XLA enabled.
Any clue of what I'm doing wrong ?

#### Edit:

So I tried to compare both output models, and also look at the gradients (using compute_gradients), to avoid weights (and then gradients) sharing I built the models in two different scopes and load separately the same weights (from a previously trained model) on both models.

I have same output if I just use:

```
sess.run([model.outputs, model2.outputs])
```

but if I also look at the gradients (first element of each tuple return by Optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)) at the same time using:

```
sess.run([model.outputs, model2.outputs, grads])
```

suddenly the model outputs are differents... How can the model output change just by looking at the gradients without using apply_gradients ? Also it doesn't seems to have changed the weights because if i'm running:

```
sess.run(grads)
sess.run([model.outputs, model.outputs2])
```

the model outputs are still the same...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that XLA is buggy here, as I have consistent results after disabling XLA. It seems that XLA can't handle something on the 2nd implementation...

I will raise an issue later on the repository about this, 'compute_gradients' modifying the outputs being particularly disturbing...